# Проблема с List. System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс Lists,  в нем два метода:

```
public static string path { get; set; }
public static List<string> L { get; set; }
public static int lineNumder { get; set; }
public static string line { get; set; }


public static void DownloadTextInList()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))//string path - путь к файлу
        while (!sr.EndOfStream) // читаем пока файл не закончится
        {
            L.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        }
}


public string GetLine()
{
    line = L.ElementAt(lineNumder);
    return line;
}
```

В классе Form1 на кнопке такой код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lists.path = @"C:\МОЯ ПАПКА\...   C#\MyRepository\технический список.txt";
    Lists.DownloadTextInList();
    string str = Lists.L.ElementAt(0);
    textBox1.AppendText(str + "\r\n");
}
```

Вроде все нормально, но при компиляции возникает ошибка: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. И она вот здесь:

```
line = L.ElementAt(lineNumder);
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 4):

Статическое поле `L` инициализируется значением `null`. Код вопроса не присваивает ему никакого значения, поэтому обращение к свойствам/методам `L` приводит к ошибке. Следует добавить код, создающий этот объект.

```
public static List<string> L { get; set; }
static Lists()
{
  L = new List<string>();
}
```

или в C# 6:

```
public static List<string> L { get; set; }  = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Игорь, благодарю вас!

Comment: @vladimirvjlga Объяснения нужны?

Comment: Игорь, если не трудно.

Comment: Как ж приятно , когда все мурлычит!
:)

Comment: Спасиб о еще раз!